# Facebook Error: 'Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data'

Tags: php, symfony

When trying to execute - $helper->getAccessToken() - gives an error -  'Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data'

Used symfony 3.3 and facebook/graph-sdk 5.4

All domains added
'FBRLH_state' exists
Session started

// Create url

```
$facebookCallbackUrl = 'https://' . $base . '/' . $_locale . '/fb-callback';
$loginfb = $this->get('app.lmfacebook')->getSigninURL($this->getParameter('fbappid'), $this->getParameter('fbsecretkey'), $facebookCallbackUrl);
```

---

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services\Ukraine;

use Facebook\Facebook;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LMFacebook extends Controller
{
    public static function getSigninURL($fbId, $fbSecret, $callback)
    {
        $fb = new Facebook([
            'app_id' => $fbId,
            'app_secret' => $fbSecret,
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
            'persistent_data_handler' => 'session'
        ]);

        $permissions = ['email'];

        return $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper()->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
    }
}
```

---

// Facebook callback

```
   /**
    * @Route("/{_locale}/fb-callback", name="fb-callback", defaults={"_locale": "ua"}, requirements={"_locale" : "ua|en|ru"})
    * @param Request $request
    * @param $_locale
    * @return mixed
    */
        public function fbCallbackAction(Request $request, $_locale)
        {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $fb = new Facebook([
            'app_id' => ********,
            'app_secret' => *******,
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
            'persistent_data_handler' => 'session'
        ]);

        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        try {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); // Error
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->logToFile('Facebook returned an error: ' . $exception->getMessage());
            exit;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Just after your `$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();` declaration try to add `$this->helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $request->query->get('state'));`.

Comment: Added `$helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $request->query->get('state'));` but the error is still playing